# Is there a way to have a using statement with dynamically-created targets?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using-statement

Let's say I've defined a class `MyDisposable : IDisposable`.  I know I can provide a hard-coded list of [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) objects to the [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement:

```
using (MyDisposable firstDisposable = new MyDisposable(),
    secondDisposable = new MyDisposable())
{
    // do something
}
```

Now let's say I have a few methods that perform operations on a collection of my disposable objects, and I want to do this inside a `using` statement.  It might look like this (but this doesn't work of course because the using block expects one or more `IDisposable` objects and I'm passing a single collection object):

```
using (var myDisposables = GetMyDisposables())
{
    foreach (var myDisposable in myDisposables)
    {
        DoSomething(myDisposable);
        DoSomethingElse(myDisposable);
    }
}
```

Here are the other methods just for clarity:

```
static List<MyDisposable> GetMyDisposables()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // return a list of MyDisposable objects
}

static void DoSomething(MyDisposable withMyDisposable)
{
    // something
}

static void DoSomethingElse(MyDisposable withMyDisposable)
{
    // something else
}
```

Is there some way I can accomplish this with the `using` statement?  Or do I do just have to throw out the statement and manually dispose?

Comment: You could create a `DisposableCollection<T> : IDisposable, IEnumerable<T> where T : IDisposable`

Comment: You can write `IDisposable` which incapsulates a collection of your `MyDisposable` objects and disposes all its elements when you dispose it.

Comment: Why don't you add your using statement inside the foreach block?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment -- because then I can't use the objects in the *next* foreach...they will have already been disposed in the first one.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Because then an error processing an item would leak all not-yet-processed items in the collection.

Comment: @roryap sorry didn't see that in your example

Comment: This is one of those questions where, upon reflection, I feel silly for even having asked it given the straightforward and "obvious" [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38101877/2704659).  I guess I wasn't seeing the forest for the trees because I was hoping there was some built-in language construct that would accommodate this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One approach that you can take is to make a collection of `IDisposable` objects, which is also `IDisposable`:

```
class CollectionOfDisposable<T> : IDisposable where T : IDisposable  {
    public IList<T> Members {get; private set;}
    public CollectionOfDisposable(IEnumerable<T> members) {
        Members = members.ToList();
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        foreach (var item in Members) {
            try {
                item.Dispose();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }
        if (exceptions.Count != 0) {
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
using (var myDisposables = GetMyDisposables()) {
    foreach (var myDisposable in myDisposables.Members) {
        DoSomething(myDisposable);
        DoSomethingElse(myDisposable);
    }
}

static CollectionOfDisposable<MyDisposable> GetMyDisposables() {
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // return a list of MyDisposable objects
}
```

Comment: Can we all agree that this class should exist in the FCL?  I can't find anything like it.  Well, actually, I found this [`System.Reactive.Disposables.CompositeDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.compositedisposable(v=vs.103).aspx) but it requires these [Reactive extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create your own type that implements `IDisposable` and accepts a collection of disposable objects in its constructor, holding onto them and disposing of them all when it is disposed.